# How to get string value json parse

Tags: android

How to get value of string from json. if `country == countryKode` not work. tanks

```
JSONObject jsonPost = new JSONObject(response.toString());
txtBody.setText(jsonPost.getString("country_name"));
final String country = String.valueOf(jsonPost.get("country_name"));
final String countryKode = "Indonesia";

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new

Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        if (country == countryKode) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Not Indonesia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like to use TextUtils.equals(“string1”, “string2”);

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
@Override
public void run() {
if (country.equals(countryKode)) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
...
```

This should work.

Comment: in case youfind it helpful, please accept the answer and upvote it :p